# HTTP Authentication with PHP

Tags: php, session

I am creating sessions if the entered username matches the one stored in my database by

$_SESSION['username'];

Now I recently learned about HTTP AUTHENTICATION with PHP using sessions to secure them.

How do I implement them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this from the PHP manual:

http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

Comment: so is the HTTP AUTH feature only for showing pop up login boxes or for securing $_SESSION too?

Comment: No, you can roll your own auth as well using forms.

Comment: is there any advantage to using this method?

Comment: @dq For http authentication, I prefer using php's functions to using htaccess, gives you a lot more control and flexibility as you don't have to use hard files.  Though i prefer to just roll my own auth rather than using http auth.